# Adding text and images to a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to add an image and a text to every list item of a `ListView`. Let me show you my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListString);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener){
@override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
...
}
}
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you for your patience and consideration.

Comment: see https://www.javatpoint.com/android-custom-listview, but look up RecyclerView if you have the chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take in consideration to use RecyclerView, to use recyclerview you need to have a list of your images (or URL's) and a list of your text's, or even better an object that contains both.

On your activity or fragment

```
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In which adapter is a RecyclerviewAdapter and RecyclerViewHolder 'cause the method you want to do is only for Strings, without a custom view. 
Please check this official documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview